# HypExp and HPL packages for hypergeometric functions: Evaluating a function HPL[{minus,plus},x]?

Tags: special-functions, packages, physics

I am currently using the [HypExp](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0507094) and [HPL](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0507152) packages, which are useful for expanding hypergeometric functions in series around integer or half-integer values, as in common in dimensional regularization for particle physics calculations.

Expanding a certain hypergeometric function gives me something of the form

```
HPL[{minus,plus}, x]
```

This is odd because HPL should only take integer values where "minus" and "plus" appear; furthermore, this function cannot be reduced by the packages. I am running Mathematica v. 11. Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: I have read them carefully and found no solution, or even any mention of "minus" or "plus".

Comment: Perhaps it might be worth just emailing the authors of this package directly.  Usually, there aren't many users of such specialized packages on here.  So I wouldn't hold your breath on an answer.

Comment: One note, instead of MathJAX it is preferable for us to have the code (if the expression of interest is in fact a Mathematica expression).

Comment: If you email the author, do point them to this thread, so they can join this site and answer future questions about their package here directly.

Comment: The solution is to use HPLpm21m1 to convert this special function to known functions. I hope I can leave this up here in case it is helpful to somebody else.

Comment: @Dwagg if you found your solution you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, use the command `HPLpm21m1[HPL[{...}, x]]` (included in the `HypExp` package) to write HPL's in terms of known functions such as polylogarithms and logarithms.

Comment: I encountered some cases where the command `HPLpm21m1[HPL[{...}, x]]` I mentioned above doesn't work. However, I found an even better solution to express the HPL's in terms of known functions: simply act with `HPLConvertToKnownFunctions[x]` where `x` is the entire expression.